# SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext() return null when running from a schedular

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am faing a problem in my spring boot application. In my application i am running a admin console page which only have login as security. no jwt token or something else.
so when i hit a controller i get respose in SecurityContext. 
but when my scheduled method runs and calls the:

```
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
```

all i get is null. i dont know how to solve this problem. can anyone help??
if you need something more please comment.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/concurrency.html

Comment: I still dont understand why it works with controller but not with scheduled threads. does httprequest cause this change? or am i going in the wrong completely direction?